# DB2 JDBC Connection Establishment - QTP

Tags: db2, qtp

Is it possible to create DB2 connection in QTP using JDBC driver?

Please guide me with some possible tips... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Tip: Research a bit, try your own solution, then post any problematic issues here as new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution !!!! :) It's very simple, if we know Java....!

Here we go - I've just written code in Java for DB2 connection establishment using `JDBC` driver and also included code for data retrieval.

And then, exported the package into **Executable JAR File** which made my job very easy. YES!!!!

After creating the **Executable JAR**, I've used the line below in QTP to access the DB2 through `JAR.`

```
SystemUtil.Run "cmd","/k java -jar C:\JarFile\DB2Connect.jar",""
```